# How do you get the location of touches for a UILongPressGestureRecognizer when the number of required touches is more than one in swift?

Tags: swift, location, touches, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I would like to get the location of multiple multiple touches from a UILongPressGuestureRecognizer where the number of required touches is more than one. I know that I can do the following to get the location when one finger is used.

```
let twoFingerLongPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(twoFingerLongPressChordTouchView(gesture:)))
twoFingerLongPressGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
twoFingerLongPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.02
self.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerLongPressGesture)
```

```
@objc func twoFingerLongPressAction(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gesture.location(in: self)
}
```

I also know that I can iterate through touches in the touches began callback however I am trying to make use of a specific behavior in UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Thanks in advance for any help or advice!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`location(ofTouch:in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624201-location) in conjunction with [`numberOfTouches`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624200-numberoftouches):

```
let touchPoints = (0..<twoFingerLongPressGesture.numberOfTouches).map {
    twoFingerLongPressGesture.location(ofTouch: $0, in: self)
}
```

This gets you all the touched points in an array of `CGPoint`s.